# Sqlline.py didn't show data *

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have create a table with `sqlline`. And inserted data to `phoenix` with `"org.apache.phoenix.spark"` library.

I can see the data in hbase and I can also load data from `phoenix` with `org.apache.phoenix.spark` library.

But I can't extract data with :

```
sqlline.py, likes
select * FROM TEST_TABLE;
```

I have found it that when i use `select key FROM TEST_TABLE (key is primary key)`
then it show's all data.

But not shows when I use the following query

```
select ID,COLUMN1 FROM TEST_TABLE
```

I think that some scheme is wrong but I am not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it.

the reason is library what i use is too old

i care about pheonix_spark
but reason is pheonix_core